# How to make a textfield with search and dropdown list in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem. I need to make a textfield with inline search. When the user enters characters into the text field, the data is searched and a drop-down list appears at the bottom with the data (as in the screenshot). But I did not find a package that could implement this feature according to my design. Does anyone know how to make a textfield with a drop down list at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package that fulfill your requirements in flutter :: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead with many other useful features

Comment: Can I customize according to my design?

Comment: Yes! you can easily do it.